# Tools for sparse least squares regression

Tags: optimization, math, statistics, regression, least-squares

I want to do sparse high dimensional (a few thousand features) least squares regression with a few hundred thousands of examples. I'm happy to use non fancy optimisation - stochastic gradient descent is fine.

Does anyone know of any software already implemented for doing this, so I don't have to write to my own?

Kind regards.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.

I was looking for something that would just handle the gradient computations and all the data wrangling for me.

In the end I couldn't find anything. R seemed to keel over with large data sets. I implemented a solution using numpy in python.

Answer (score 5):

While I don't know for sure, this strikes me as the kind of thing that [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) (linear algebra package) would be able to provide support for.  They are typically interested in large matrix math, incluing sparse matrices and out-of-core sizes.  The basic version is FORTRAN, but there are ports of the libraries for C and other languages.

As LAPACK uses BLAS (basic linear algebra subprograms) for many of its underlying calls, you will probably also want to check out [Sparse BLAS](http://math.nist.gov/spblas/).

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that the [R package](http://www.r-project.org/) can be used for problems like this.  It's incredibly powerful and flexible.  Lots of online resources linked from that page.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest taking a look at [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/).  It's a pretty mature linear algebra library, although interfacing with it can be a little tricky, since it's written in Fortran.  That's fine, though, since Fortran is ABI compatible with C, if you get your function prototypes right.

[Edit] Upon further review, it appears that LAPACK does not support sparse matrices.  It can handle banded matrices for some purposes, but for the linear least-squares problem, it only supports general matrices.